# CSS - need help horizontally centering contents within a fluid width div

Tags: css

I've looked around for answers and I've tried plugging in everything I can think of, but I can't seem to figure this one out. I feel like I'm probably overlooking something really simple and obvious, but any help you can give would be really appreciated!

Basically I'm trying to customize [this page](http://emirin.tumblr.com/muselist) so that the little character boxes are horizontally centered within their .wrapper div.

While the div itself is centered horizontally in the middle of the page (I've used padding: 0 15% for that), the content **inside** it is not.

[Here is a pastebin of the entire code](http://pastebin.com/LBV02Gh2) if anyone would like it. The relevant section is line 140. Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: [Here's a better picture](http://i.imgur.com/ax4hKCq.jpg) illustrating what I mean when I say that the contents aren't centered.

Comment: could you please add a snippet? external links are not advisable in question unless you post the relevant code too...

Comment: The relevant section is `    .wrapper {
        background-color:#eee;
        max-height:100%;
        padding:0 15%;
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }`
but it seems like the person below has worked out that it's not the CSS that's screwing it up but the javascript. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the div containing the individual character boxes are using absolute positioning so any style you try to use on the wrapper div that contains them to center them will be overwritten by the absolute positioning. You could probably change the javascript that is writing the absolute positions to center the boxes in the wrapper div or you could possibly pad the wrapper. I was playing around with the numbers and had a couple boxes centered within the wrapper div but when it's resized the javascript rewrites the positions. I would've used bootstrap to make this page instead of using javascript to reposition things on resize.

Comment: Ahhhh I see, thank you! Yes, that makes sense.

I didn't write the javascript code and don't know anything about js or bootstrap unfortunately, but thanks for the help!!

Comment: Ok I tried to pad it and while it worked for what was visible, when it's resized  the padding changes so it will have to be fixed in the javascript that is writing the positions for the div's containing the character info.

Comment: It could actually be the margin you added to it throwing it off. Try to remove the margin you added and see if the boxes are centered then.

Comment: Nah I tried that already. The result is still the same, just on a larger scale :(. IF ONLY ...

Comment: Actually, I removed the padding you put in the css and then the wrapper fills that whole section and positions the character boxes accordingly, which is probably what the author of the site intended.

Comment: Yes, that's true! But even when it fills the whole section (which isn't what I want anyway) it still isn't exactly centered. On my screen it's a little bit off to the right.

Comment: Well you could wrap the wrapper in another div that is positioned and sized like you want. And then center the wrapper in the new div and it could possibly center things up. The javascript is putting things in the wrapper so another surrounding div that constrains the wrapper to your specifications should clear up the problem. You may have to change up the inline styles on the wrapper tho because it is positioned relatively.

Comment: Ooooooooohh I never thought of that. That could work! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is

1) Remove padding on your wrapper div and set text-align center

2) For each of the character box, I am not sure what you are using the javascript for. If the javascript have no other use other than making those boxes horizontally center, you can remove it.

.chara remove the float center, remove height, add display inline-block, add padding 25px 0

3) .charaimg remove position relative, remove top, remove left

4) .charatitle remove height, remove position absolute, remove bottom 0

5) In your HTML switch the .charaimg and .charatitle

That should do.

And also for future question, it helps a lot if you can put your code in codepen or jsfiddle. It makes life easier for people who are helping you.

Comment: The javascript is for the filtering code, actually! It's not working at the moment because I haven't set the tags up. Thank you anyway for the help! I've managed to get it working with the div inside a div solution :). And I'll remember that for future use. Thanks!!